# Where is the APK file in PhoneGap after compile it?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I just installed Phonegap and created the app through the terminal (command line), everything works fine. It compiled the code and exported it to my smartphone, that was connected to PC.

The problem is, where PhoneGap storage the APK file after use the command "`phonegap run android`" or "`phonegap compile android`"?

Comment: don't you get that in bin folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just founded that is inside app folder:

/--app folder--/platform/android/bin/~

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this step if u r using eclipse

Right Click on the Project -> Android Tools ->Export Unsigned Application Package

to release from the command line:
 http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#ReleaseMode
…

to sign the .apk file, if you need to do :

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Actually I'm using only the Terminal, didn't open the Eclipse for the process.