# APK missing after phonegap build?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

Thread number onehundredeleven. I already tried the recommendations from [Where is APK file after "phonegap build android" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853131/where-is-apk-file-after-phonegap-build-android-command), [Where is APK file stored after phonegap android build is successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614437/where-is-apk-file-stored-after-phonegap-android-build-is-successful), [Where is my apk file for my android application? (via eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219493/where-is-my-apk-file-for-my-android-application-via-eclipse), [Where is the APK file in PhoneGap after compile it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256306/where-is-the-apk-file-in-phonegap-after-compile-it) and [Location of .apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039862/location-of-apk-file), but the mystery remains unsolved:

After successfully (= without error message) executing `sencha app build native` and/or `phonegap build android`, I can't find an APK on my computer.

```
X:\mySenchaTouchApp\phonegap>phonegap version
4.2.0-0.24.2

X:\mySenchaTouchApp\phonegap>phonegap build --release
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build --release'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build --release'
```

The folders `X:\mySenchaTouchApp\phonegap\platforms\android\bin` and `X:\mySenchaTouchApp\phonegap\platforms\android\ant-bin` did not exist, I created both, ran `phonegap build` again, but both are still empty.

A windows search for `*.apk` in the project directory came up blank, searching over my whole computer only spotted some sample apps in `C:\Users\alexander\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-19\legacy` and a downloaded apk file in my Downloads folder.

It does not work with `--release`, without `--release`, with `android`, without with `android`, with `local` or without `local`. **It works fine if I do a remote build.**

I find it confusing that no error is thrown and no apk is built, is it just me?

Is there a hidden switch anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this instead

```
cordova build android --release
```

and it should generate the apk in platforms\android\ant-build

It seems there are many issues when using the phonegap cli (behaviour varying on each version) that's why I now stick to cordova cli only.